# Find files but exclude several directories?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, shell, bash-scripting

How do I use `find` to list every single file but exclude a handful of directories from the search?

```
find / -type f -not -path "./foo*" -not -path "/bar*" -print
```

I've seen examples on other stackexchanges, eg `./`, but nothing I've tried seems to work.

This kinda works:

```
find / -type f -not -path "*foo*" -not -path "*bar*" -print
```

But not really; it also excludes files named "foo" and "bar" from the search results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`find / -type f -not -path "*foo*/*" -not -path "*bar*/*" -print` seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

exclude directories during find

```
sudo find ~ -iname "*s40*" ! -path "*timeshift*"
```

this command searches in the Home directory  /home/username
and finds files (or directories) containing the text
s40
but ignores all paths containing the text
timeshift

-iname   selects files by name, but ignores case (upper/lower)
the exclamation mark means NOT, and    find    also recognises
-not -path "*timeshift*"

the  sudo  avoids producing a long list of    Permission denied