# cannot exclude some paths using find command

Tags: linux, find

beeing in my home directory, I want to find all files within my current directory excluding these 2 directories:

```
./.mozilla
./.cache/mozilla
```

following this solution: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/508054/using-find-to-exclude-multiple-paths-matching-patterns

```
find . \( -path "/home/achille/.cache/mozilla/*" -o -path "/home/achille/.mozilla/*" \) -prune -o -type f -print | grep mozilla
```

following this solution: [Find files but exclude several directories?](https://superuser.com/questions/1243853/find-files-but-exclude-several-directories)

```
find . -not -path "/home/achille/.cache/mozilla/*" -not -path "/home/achille/.mozilla/*" -type f -print | grep mozilla
```

following this solution : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132210/use-find-command-but-exclude-files-in-two-directories

```
find . -type f ! -path "/home/achille/.cache/mozilla/*" ! -path "/home/achille/.mozilla/*" -print | grep mozilla
```

(for each of these attempts, I also tried '/home/achille' instead of '.'. Expecting no output for each command, I have got instead the following:

```
  [...]

./.cache/mozilla/firefox/lnzaa3h4.default/safebrowsing/ads-track-digest256.pset
```

Comment: state your OS,  for example it's clearly not windows, even though windows has a find command

Comment: Stream-Centos - 4.18.0-147.6.el8.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Oct 15 15:19:32 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: just tried: find . ! \( -path "/home/achille/.cache/mozilla/*" -o -path "/home/achille/.mozilla/*" \) -print | grep mozilla -> pb remains.

Comment: `-path` does not match paths by their equivalency in the directory tree, it matches them as *strings*. You specified `.` as the only starting location, so *every* path tested starts with `.`. You provided paths you want to exclude as strings starting with `/home/achille/`. They cannot match anything that starts with `.`. Then you said "I also tried `/home/achille` instead of `.`", but what you got ("I have got instead the following") starts with `.`. This doesn't fit. Please verify or/and elaborate. I think I'm on the right track but the incoherence in the question stops me from answering.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach.

If you are really want to ignore **all** '.mozilla' and '.cache/mozilla' files. This basically matches all files, except those matching these two patterns.

```
find . -not -name ".mozilla" -and -not -wholename ".cache/mozilla" -print
```

Where

```
-not       means negate the following command
-name      is the name of the file you are (or not) looking for
-and       means matching first test and the second test must pass
-wholename matches name with a path.
-print     display the results  (also is optional since default is display result)
```

On the other hand, here is the opposite,find only those files which match the two patterns.

```
$ find . -name "mozilla" -or -name "*.mozilla"
```

Example results

```
 $ find . -name ".mozilla"

./.mozilla

 $ find . -name "mozilla"

./.cache/mozilla

 $ find . -name "mozilla" -or -name "*.mozilla"

./.mozilla
./.cache/mozilla
```

Interesting enough, when '-print' is added at the end of the line. Only one result is returned.

```
 $ find . -name "mozilla" -or -name "*.mozilla" -print
./.mozilla
```

So need to add parens

```
 $ find . \( -name "mozilla" -or -name "*.mozilla" \) -print
./.mozilla
./.cache/mozilla
```

Or add -print to both sides of the -or statement

```
 $ find . -name "mozilla" -print -or -name "*.mozilla" -print
./.mozilla
./.cache/mozilla
```